# Chrome randomly fails to clear the cache when hitting CTRL+R

Tags: google-chrome, caching

This issue seems completely random: sometimes, Chrome just won't clear the cache, even after multiple `CTRL+R`, in which case going to Settings & manually "Clear Browsing Cache" is the only way to clear it and finally see the last CSS/SCSS applied.

Is there a definite solution to this annoying problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+R only does a normal reload in chrome.  What you want to do is use Ctrl+Shift+R to do a hard reload.